# UIKit crashes in iOS

Tags: ios, crash, uikit, xcode8, crash-reports

I've recently got a crash log from my app which was released to pilot users. When I look through Xcode the crash log points to `UIKit: -[UIEventFetcher _receiveHIDEventInternal:] + 220` This issue is not reproducible so I'm kind of stuck on how to debug this crash or what could be causing it. Below is a crash log for the same.

```
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.1.2 
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000030
VM Region Info: 0x30 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4329832400
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 0000000102140000-0000000102144000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...My App]

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  1

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018597e1c8 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 1288 (NSArrayM_Common.h:278)
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018597de50 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 400 (NSArrayM_Common.h:256)
2   My App                  0x0000000102362bfc CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 404
3   My App                  0x00000001023628a0 CLSTerminateHandler() + 396
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000184cef54c std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:66)
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000184cef158 __cxa_rethrow + 144 (cxa_exception.cpp:557)
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000184d006e8 objc_exception_rethrow + 44 (objc-exception.mm:559)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185978024 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 544 (CFRunLoop.c:3259)
8   GraphicsServices                0x000000018780ff84 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
9   UIKit                           0x000000018ef4c2e8 UIApplicationMain + 208 (UIApplication.m:3949)
10  My App                  0x00000001021ff514 main + 92 (main.m:14)
11  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018549a56c start + 4

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018597e1c8 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 1288 (NSArrayM_Common.h:278)
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018597de50 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 400 (NSArrayM_Common.h:256)
2   UIKit                           0x000000018faab55c -[UIEventFetcher _receiveHIDEventInternal:] + 220 (UIEventFetcher.m:229)
3   IOKit                           0x0000000185d46170 __IOHIDEventSystemClientQueueCallback + 236 (IOHIDEventSystemClient.c:1037)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185a40010 __CFMachPortPerform + 188 (CFMachPort.c:689)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185a5a96c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56 (CFRunLoop.c:1998)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185a5a070 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 440 (CFRunLoop.c:2135)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185a57b44 __CFRunLoopRun + 2196 (CFRunLoop.c:3150)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185977fb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
9   Foundation                      0x00000001863a16e4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
10  Foundation                      0x00000001863c0afc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96 (NSRunLoop.m:411)
11  UIKit                           0x000000018faab2f4 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136 (UIEventFetcher.m:436)
12  Foundation                      0x00000001864a2860 __NSThread__start__ + 996 (NSThread.m:1181)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dc31c _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dc1e8 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dac28 thread_start + 4

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001855aa670 write + 8
1   My App                  0x0000000102358d0c CLSSDKFileLog + 336
2   My App                  0x0000000102350338 CLSMachExceptionServer + 1148
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dc31c _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dc1e8 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dac28 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001855a8bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001855a8a3c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185a59c74 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 (CFRunLoop.c:2613)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185a57840 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424 (CFRunLoop.c:2969)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185977fb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
5   CFNetwork                       0x00000001860e2264 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 404 (NSURLConnection.mm:367)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001864a2860 __NSThread__start__ + 996 (NSThread.m:1181)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dc31c _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dc1e8 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dac28 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001855c9150 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856ded30 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640 (pthread_cond.c:579)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000184c82ea4 std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24 (__threading_support:278)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd25b94 void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >(std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 96 (condition_variable:202)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd25abc bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadRunLoop() + 172 (condition_variable:211)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018cd25e20 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*), bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*> >(void*) + 44 (type_traits:4291)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dc31c _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dc1e8 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dac28 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001855a8bc4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001855a8a3c mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185a59c74 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196 (CFRunLoop.c:2613)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185a57840 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424 (CFRunLoop.c:2969)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185977fb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
5   WebCore                         0x000000018d7ebe04 RunWebThread(void*) + 456 (WebCoreThread.mm:694)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dc31c _pthread_body + 308 (pthread.c:740)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dc1e8 _pthread_start + 312 (pthread.c:799)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dac28 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dac1c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001855c9dbc __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856db134 _pthread_wqthread + 1288 (pthread.c:0)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dac20 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001856dac1c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 1 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000001   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000000000006  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x00000000fffffff0
   x12: 0x0000000000000058  x13: 0x00000000fffffff0  x14: 0x0000000185615f89  x15: 0x000000000000004d
   x16: 0x00000001856d1de0  x17: 0x000000018597dcc0  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000018fc6dd6a  x21: 0x0000000000000000  x22: 0x0000000217cf4450  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x00000001c0ba4d00  x26: 0x00000001c4240550  x27: 0x00000001b489518c
   x28: 0x0000000000000006   fp: 0x000000016df74c20   lr: 0x000000018597de50
    sp: 0x000000016df74b80   pc: 0x000000018597e1c8 cpsr: 0x20000000
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you ever resolve this issue? I'm seeing a similar crash log in Xcode, but cannot seem to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

One crash on one phone from one user?........

Chalk it up to "Stuff Happens" and move on - you can't possibly track down all possible issues that happen in a phone - at least, not if you are going to ever get the app finished and out to the public.

If you really "have to" find this, then you should get more testers so it CAN be duplicated.

One-off issues just aren't worth the trouble.

Comment: This count has went upto 3. I have crashlytics installed in my app. One thing I noticed each crash device has only about 1-4% of free RAM. Could that be a potential cause?

Comment: still, a count of 3 is hard to say much - how many tests does that cover?  If it is 3, then you have a serious problem, but if it is 100000, then not so much...  However, that RAM number does look odd - I'd check in Xcode to see how much is running at different parts of the app - you may find some of your code is running away.  Also I would consider tracking didReceiveMemoryWarning and look to do something with that.